# Do the inputs to a boolean-function need to be boolean variables?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

That is, say we had the following:
define a set, $A$, as: 
$A = \{x,y,z\}$

If we had a function which only takes the elements of $A$ as its inputs, and returns "true" if $x$ is an input and false if $x$ is not an input, then is this technically considered a boolean-function?

I have always seen boolean-functions defined in terms of giving a true/false output when it's inputs are boolean-variables (true or false themselves).

But here, true/false is not being applied to the inputs.

Would this function meet the definition of a boolean-function?

Basically, is a boolean function defined as a function which, regardless of the inputs, only has true/false as outputs? 
Or do the inputs need to be true/false values themselves?

Answer (score 1):

A Boolean function is defined to be a function $f:\{0,1\}^n\to\{0,1\}$, so both the input and the output needs to be true/false values.

Functions $f:X\to\{0,1\}$ are known as *indicator functions*. It's called this because the set $f^{-1}(1)=A$. Then $f(x)$ takes on the value $1$ exactly when $x\in A$, so it indicates membership in the set $A$. This is often denoted $\chi_A(x)$ when this property is important.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Could you explain a bit more what the 'n' means in this context? And ah, ok, I see your edit in regards to indicator functions. That is what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: $n$ is the number of variables. I.e., $f$ takes as input a tuple of $n$ $o/1$ values: $f(0,1,1,1,0,0,\dots,0,0,1,1,1,0)$

Comment: $n$ denotes the number of variables that $f$ takes as an input. So if you have $f(x)$, then $n=1$. If you have $f(x_1,...,x_{11})$ then $n=11$. The notation $f:X^n\to Y$ means that $f$ is a function of $n$ variables with each variable is a member of the set $X$, and has output in the set $Y$

Comment: Ook, thanks, got it.